# Package bbold not working

Tags: fonts, errors, amsmath, miktex

I've been trying to use the `bbold` package for the indicator function but I get the following error:

```
Process started

This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (C:

\Users\somename\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\source\jknappen\saut

er\bbold11.m f ! I can't find file `b-bbold'. l.2 input b-bbo

ld ; Please type another input file name ! Emergency stop. l.2 input b-bbold ; Transcrip

t written on bbold11.log.

Sorry, but maketfm did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:/Users/Chris/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/miktex-maketfm.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

Process exited with error(s)
```

The log file says:

```
2016-05-23 14:35:43,127+0100 INFO  makex - Making bbold11.tfm from C:\Users\somename\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts\source\jknappen\sauter\bbold11.mf...
2016-05-23 14:35:43,130+0100 INFO  makex - Running miktex-mf.exe...
2016-05-23 14:35:43,281+0100 FATAL miktex-maketfm - Windows API error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.

2016-05-23 14:35:43,281+0100 FATAL miktex-maketfm - Info: existing="bbold11.tfm", new="C:\Users\somename\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\fonts/tfm/jknappen/sauter\bbold11.tfm"
2016-05-23 14:35:43,281+0100 FATAL miktex-maketfm - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\File\win\winFile.cpp
2016-05-23 14:35:43,281+0100 FATAL miktex-maketfm - Line: 308
```

Also:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.1.10)  23 MAY 2016 14:39
entering extended mode
**./s.tex
(s.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 69 languages loaded.
("C:\Users\somename\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Users\somename\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size11.clo"
File: size11.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) ("C:\Users\somename\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\bbold\bbold.sty"
Package: bbold 1994/04/06 Bbold symbol package
)

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.5 I
 f $V_i = \displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=0}\mathbb{1}_{X_n = i}$ is the num...

You're in trouble here.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.

LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <10.95> on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+bbold on input line 5.
("C:\Users\somename\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\jknappen\ubbold.fd
"
File: ubbold.fd 1996/01/01 Blackboard Bold Font Definition File (jk)
)
! Font U/bbold/m/n/10.95=bbold11 at 10.95pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not
 found.
<to be read again> 
               relax 
l.5 ... = \displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=0}\mathbb{1}
                                              _{X_n = i}$ is the number ...
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

! \textfont 4 is undefined (character 1).
l.5 ...style\sum^\infty_{n=0}\mathbb{1}_{X_n = i}$
                                               is the number of visits t...
Somewhere in the math formula just ended, you used the
stated character from an undefined font family. For example,
plain TeX doesn't allow \it or \sl in subscripts. Proceed,
and I'll try to forget that I needed that character.

! \textfont 4 is undefined (character E).
l.5 ...laystyle\sum^\infty_{n=0}\mathbb{P}(X_n=i)$
                                              .
Somewhere in the math formula just ended, you used the
stated character from an undefined font family. For example,
plain TeX doesn't allow \it or \sl in subscripts. Proceed,
and I'll try to forget that I needed that character.

! \textfont 4 is undefined (character P).
l.5 ...laystyle\sum^\infty_{n=0}\mathbb{P}(X_n=i)$
                                              .
Somewhere in the math formula just ended, you used the
stated character from an undefined font family. For example,
plain TeX doesn't allow \it or \sl in subscripts. Proceed,
and I'll try to forget that I needed that character.

[1

{C:/Users/somename/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
! I can't find file `s.aux'.
\enddocument ...keatletter \@@input \jobname .aux 
                                              \fi \@dofilelist \ifdim \f...
l.7 \end{document}

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
\enddocument ...keatletter \@@input \jobname .aux 
                                              \fi \@dofilelist \ifdim \f...
l.7 \end{document}

*** (job aborted, file error in nonstop mode)


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 244 strings out of 493634
 3084 string characters out of 3135239
 52604 words of memory out of 3000000
 3701 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 6746 words of font info for 25 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1025 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 21i,4n,19p,352b,113s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{bbold}
\begin{document}
If $V_i = \displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=0}\mathbb{1}_{X_n = i}$ is the number of visits to $i$, then $\mathbb{E}[V_i] = \displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=0}\mathbb{P}(X_n=i)$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your system tries to create a bbold**11**.tfm ? Remove from your example all the unneeded packages and then compile again and show the log-file.  (On my miktex your example works fine but it doesn't to use the sauter fonts).

Comment: Which packages are removable? I assume that `upgreek` is, but I'm not sure about the others.

Comment: Try it out. Remove one package, compile and if the error is still there the package wasn't necessary to demonstrate the problem. Continue with the next package.

Comment: Well, I've managed to remove every package one by one and still have the error...

Comment: Perhaps you should reread by first comment until the end.

Comment: Sorry! I was caught up wondering why I could remove `amsmath` and still have the same error. I'll edit in the new error log into the question.

Comment: Edit also the question and show also your current (shortened) document.

Comment: Done, hopefully it's okay now?

Comment: Show the log-file of the compilation of your minimal example (not the miktex-mf-log.)

Comment: Edited the question again.

Comment: Seufz. The log file is a file with the ending .log. Find it, it should be in the same folder as your tex-file.

Comment: Edited once again.

Comment: I don't think that you really compiled the example you showed -- there is a \begin{document} missing. Beside this deinstall with the package manager the jknappen package. It contains a file which breaks the bbold fonts.

Comment: @jknappen: Would it be better to remove ubbold.fd from the jknappen package on CTAN? (texlive already seems not to distribuate it.)

Comment: For what it's worth, I was having exactly this problem with MikTeX, and simply running the update facility solved it.  Anyone else arriving here with the same issue might simply check that their TeX distribution is completely up to date.

Comment: Updating fixed it for me...and then updating again a few weeks later brought back the same error. Sigh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your TeX distribution is a little bit outdated and that causes your problem. Please see The following lines:

```
Mine system: Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 ... (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.1.29) ...
Your system:         3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 ... (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.1.10) ...
%                                                                                 ^^
```

The difference is `preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.1.10` to `2016.1.29`

So with the following MWE (I only added some line breaks for better readability):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{bbold}
\begin{document}
If $V_i = \displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=0}\mathbb{1}_{X_n = i}$ is the 
number of visits to $i$, then 
$\mathbb{E}[V_i] = \displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=0}\mathbb{P}(X_n=i)$.
\end{document}
```

I get the following result without errors or warnings:

[image: result of mwe above]

and the log file (including `\listfiles` result):

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2016.1.29)  23 MAY 2016 19:17
entering extended mode
**./311015.tex
(311015.tex
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9n> and hyphenation patterns for 69 languages loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size11.clo"
File: size11.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\bbold\bbold.sty"
Package: bbold 1994/04/06 Bbold symbol package
)
(311015.aux)
\openout1 = `311015.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <10.95> on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <8> on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `cmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <6> on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for U+bbold on input line 6.
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\bbold\ubbold.fd") [1

{C:/Users/Internet/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}] (311015.aux)

 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size11.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
   bbold.sty    1994/04/06 Bbold symbol package
  ubbold.fd
 ***********

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 245 strings out of 493634
 2815 string characters out of 3143735
 52604 words of memory out of 3000000
 3699 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 6935 words of font info for 26 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1025 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 21i,4n,23p,178b,107s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
<C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/bbold-type1/bbold10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/publi
c/amsfonts/cm/cmex10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX
 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi6.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi8.pfb><C:/
Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfon
ts/cm/cmr8.pfb><C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmsy8.pfb>
Output written on 311015.pdf (1 page, 64777 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 38 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Finally a trusted user ;-) (+1)

Comment: @Christian Hupfer; On testing I had the same problem as the user, and had to make the `.tfm`s by hand.

Comment: @Bernard: Huh?????????

Comment: My system is not outdated and I could reproduce the error by installing the jknappen package http://www.ctan.org/pkg/jknappen. In miktex (but not in texlive) in contains a second ubbold.fd and if this is found first (which can but don't have to happen) you get problems. To test the issue: get the "jknappen"-ubbold.fd from CTAN and put it in the folder of your document.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I can confirm this is still an issue. Just ran into it myself with MikTeX, and removing the `jknappen` package fixed it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer , could this be made an answer? I've missed the comment the first time I saw the post (being from 2016 and knowing my distribution was not outdated, I discarded it pretty quickly).

Comment: @SomeUser I suggest that you tackle the problem at the root: Open an issue at the miktex issue tracker and ask the maintainer if he can remove the duplicate in the jknappen package (as texlive already does). Additionally write ctan and notify them about the duplicate. They can probably reach the maintainer.

Comment: I could not reproduce the error (I have tried both re-installing the jknappen package from the MikTeX Console and downloading jknappen's ubbold.fd from CTAN and putting it in some MWE's folder). When/if the error comes up again (as I am keeping the package installed), I will open the issue.